# Retrofit response is null

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I'm using retorfit to fetch data from the Steam api, but my response is null, however the logging shows the correct JSON response.

This is the Json from the API:

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561197960435530",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "Robin",
            "lastlogoff": 1508048552,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/robinwalker/",
            "avatar": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 0,
            "realname": "Robin Walker",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791429521412",
            "timecreated": 1063407589,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "US",
            "locstatecode": "WA",
            "loccityid": 3961
        }
    ]
}
```

}

These are my Pojos:

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("players")
private List<Player> mPlayers;

public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return mPlayers;
}

public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
    mPlayers = players;
}
```

}

```
public class Player {

@SerializedName("avatar")
private String mAvatar;
@SerializedName("avatarfull")
private String mAvatarfull;
@SerializedName("avatarmedium")
private String mAvatarmedium;
@SerializedName("communityvisibilitystate")
private Long mCommunityvisibilitystate;
@SerializedName("lastlogoff")
private Long mLastlogoff;
@SerializedName("loccityid")
private Long mLoccityid;
@SerializedName("loccountrycode")
private String mLoccountrycode;
@SerializedName("locstatecode")
private String mLocstatecode;
@SerializedName("personaname")
private String mPersonaname;
@SerializedName("personastate")
private Long mPersonastate;
@SerializedName("personastateflags")
private Long mPersonastateflags;
@SerializedName("primaryclanid")
private String mPrimaryclanid;
@SerializedName("profilestate")
private Long mProfilestate;
@SerializedName("profileurl")
private String mProfileurl;
@SerializedName("realname")
private String mRealname;
@SerializedName("response")
private Response mResponse;
@SerializedName("steamid")
private String mSteamid;
@SerializedName("timecreated")
private Long mTimecreated;

public String getAvatar() {
    return mAvatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    mAvatar = avatar;
}

public String getAvatarfull() {
    return mAvatarfull;
}

public void setAvatarfull(String avatarfull) {
    mAvatarfull = avatarfull;
}

public String getAvatarmedium() {
    return mAvatarmedium;
}

public void setAvatarmedium(String avatarmedium) {
    mAvatarmedium = avatarmedium;
}

public Long getCommunityvisibilitystate() {
    return mCommunityvisibilitystate;
}

public void setCommunityvisibilitystate(Long communityvisibilitystate) {
    mCommunityvisibilitystate = communityvisibilitystate;
}

public Long getLastlogoff() {
    return mLastlogoff;
}

public void setLastlogoff(Long lastlogoff) {
    mLastlogoff = lastlogoff;
}

public Long getLoccityid() {
    return mLoccityid;
}

public void setLoccityid(Long loccityid) {
    mLoccityid = loccityid;
}

public String getLoccountrycode() {
    return mLoccountrycode;
}

public void setLoccountrycode(String loccountrycode) {
    mLoccountrycode = loccountrycode;
}

public String getLocstatecode() {
    return mLocstatecode;
}

public void setLocstatecode(String locstatecode) {
    mLocstatecode = locstatecode;
}

public String getPersonaname() {
    return mPersonaname;
}

public void setPersonaname(String personaname) {
    mPersonaname = personaname;
}

public Long getPersonastate() {
    return mPersonastate;
}

public void setPersonastate(Long personastate) {
    mPersonastate = personastate;
}

public Long getPersonastateflags() {
    return mPersonastateflags;
}

public void setPersonastateflags(Long personastateflags) {
    mPersonastateflags = personastateflags;
}

public String getPrimaryclanid() {
    return mPrimaryclanid;
}

public void setPrimaryclanid(String primaryclanid) {
    mPrimaryclanid = primaryclanid;
}

public Long getProfilestate() {
    return mProfilestate;
}

public void setProfilestate(Long profilestate) {
    mProfilestate = profilestate;
}

public String getProfileurl() {
    return mProfileurl;
}

public void setProfileurl(String profileurl) {
    mProfileurl = profileurl;
}

public String getRealname() {
    return mRealname;
}

public void setRealname(String realname) {
    mRealname = realname;
}

public Response getResponse() {
    return mResponse;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    mResponse = response;
}

public String getSteamid() {
    return mSteamid;
}

public void setSteamid(String steamid) {
    mSteamid = steamid;
}

public Long getTimecreated() {
    return mTimecreated;
}

public void setTimecreated(Long timecreated) {
    mTimecreated = timecreated;
}
```

}

And here is my request:

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getPlayers());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<com.example.konem.pubgstat.Models.Response> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

I tried a few workaround but I can't get it to work, the response.body.getPlayers() always return null. 
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with the serialization, I missed one Java class, now I have three Pojos and working perfectly:

```
  @SerializedName("response")
@Expose
private Response_ response;

public Response_ getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response_ response) {
    this.response = response;
}



public class Response_ {

@SerializedName("players")
@Expose
private List<Player> players = null;

public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
    this.players = players;
}
```

}

And the players class.

Comment: please, can you copy and paste the logs when you make the call and the response back?
probably your data model is correct, but you actually receive a null response.

Comment: My data model was incorrect, I missed one class, the response was always good :)